# How to use $promise of angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a async rest call. The response is retrieved at the end after everything else is called. I need the response before it goes to next step.
I planned to implement promise.
I don't know how to implement promise in my case.
My Code:

```
if($scope.savedDesc.length <= 0 && $scope.savedDesc != null && $scope.savedDesc != 'undefined') {
    access.getDesc($scope.id, function(data){
        $scope.savedDesc = data;
    });
}
```

when the $scope.savedDesc is set, then only I want to proceed to next step.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: call your next step in `callback` function i.e after line `$scope.saveDesc`.

Comment: @gauravbhavsar: I have foreach after the $scope.savedDesc = data, Where I will set variable noteDesc. The noteDesc is passed to another rest call.  Since the $scope.savedDesc is not setting, the noteDesc is passed as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($scope.savedDesc.length <= 0 && $scope.savedDesc != null && $scope.savedDesc != 'undefined') {
    access.getDesc($scope.id, function(data){
        $scope.savedDesc = data;
    });
}

// next step(s) here...
```

To

```
if($scope.savedDesc.length <= 0 && $scope.savedDesc != null && $scope.savedDesc != 'undefined') {
    access.getDesc($scope.id, function(data){
        $scope.savedDesc = data;

        // next step(s) here...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `access` is a [angular `$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), you may do something like this:

```
function nextStep(){
    //...do something with $scope.savedDesc...
}

$scope.savedDesc = access.getDesc($scope.id, nextStep);

// or

$scope.savedDesc = access.getDesc($scope.id);
//... (do something else)
$scope.savedDesc.$promise.then(nextStep);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callback` function to achieve step by step execution.

```
if($scope.savedDesc.length <= 0 && $scope.savedDesc != null && $scope.savedDesc != 'undefined')
{
    access.getDesc($scope.id, function(data){
        $scope.savedDesc = data;
        noteDescCall($scope.savedDesc); // call foreach inside this function with $scope.saveDesc
    });
}

// your noteDescCall function which have `foreach` loop

function noteDescCall(savedDesc){
    // implementation with savedDesc ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP asked about promises. Here's a simple promise chaining example:

```
MyAsyncRestCall()
  .then(function(result1) {
    // you can modify `result1` before returning it if you want
    return result1;
  })
  .then(function(result2) {
    // `result2` is the data returned from the above `then` (e.g. `result1`)
    // returning `result2` returns the value to the original caller
    return result2;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle errors here if you want to
    return $q.reject({ message: JSON.stringify(error) });
  });
```

Here's a good article about promise chaining: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promise-chaining-explained